# Vaadin login issue with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin14

I'm having a weird issue with Vaadin (v. 14.6.1) and Spring boot (v. 2.4.5). I have followed the instructions in https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/securing-your-app-with-spring-security/setting-up-spring-security, to implement login view and security setup.

When i load the app and goto localhost/8080 to login, i enter correct credentials but login fails with the message

**WARN 8184 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.v.f.s.c.UidlRequestHandler             : Invalid security key received from 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1**

when I try to login again with the same credentials, login succeeds. if i logout and try to login again, it works fine.

I can reproduce this issue by restarting the server and trying to login again. i tested this issue in dev mode and production mode, and got the same behavior.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but it looks like a bug. The exception is thrown If the received security key does not match the one stored in the session and in the first request you don't have a session. Could you share your project that I can have a look?

Comment: Here is the link for the code, https://github.com/lutfijd/VaadinLoginIssue

Comment: I can reproduce the problem. I have a similar application where this problem does not happend. I'll keep you updated

Comment: Thanks Simon, I probably should have clarified earlier that I'm new to Vaadin and this is an issue in sample code i was experimenting with, Please dont spend too much of your time on it.

Answer (score 1):

I found two issues with your code:

1. SecurityUtils

The `ServletHelper` class is deprecated and I believe that causes the problem. I replaced it with `HandlerHelper`:

```
public class SecurityUtils {

    /**
     * Tests if the request is an internal framework request. The test consists of
     * checking if the request parameter is present and if its value is consistent
     * with any of the request types know.
     *
     * @param request
     *            {@link HttpServletRequest}
     * @return true if is an internal framework request. False otherwise.
     */
    static boolean isFrameworkInternalRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        final String parameterValue = request.getParameter(ApplicationConstants.REQUEST_TYPE_PARAMETER);
        return parameterValue != null && Stream.of(HandlerHelper.RequestType.values())
                .anyMatch(r -> r.getIdentifier().equals(parameterValue));
    }
```

2. Vaadin Plugin was missing (just a side note if you run it with Maven the prepare-frontend must be run)

pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks Simon. Before I added your changes I tried to test the app and make sure I can still reproduce the issue, to my amazement I could not. After a while of head scratching, I realized that i changed the server port on the app from 8080 to 80. Unfortunately, the changes you suggested didn't fix the issue while on port 8080.

I can confirm that changing the server port from 8080 to 80 actually fixes this issue, I repeatedly started the server with different port # to make sure this wasn't just some fluke. but the issue consistently goes away on port 80 and appears again on port 8080.

Comment: In regards to adding the vaadin frontend plugin to the pom, please keep in mind this pom was generated by spring initializer and not me, so if its not there I can only presume Vaadin team or spring team didn't think they needed it there.